# Youtube_It example code draws Argument Error

Tags: ruby, youtube, youtube-api

I wrote some basic code to try and get the library working. I am operating on Windows 7, and I just installed the youtube_it gem and attempted to run some example code from the readme, however, I received a puzzling ArgumentError. Here is the code that I tried to run:

```
#Test YouTube Ruby file. 
require 'youtube_it'
client = YouTubeIt::Client.new(:dev_key => "my developer key here)
client.videos_by(:query => "penguin", :max_results => 1)
client.videos.each do |video|
  video.title
  video.video_id
end
```

`For reference, the error received was this: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/rubygems/1.9.1/gems/youtube_it-2.3.1/lib/youtube_it/request/video_upload.rb:265: in 'videos' wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError).`

Any input as to how I could go about troubleshooting this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to close your dev key quotes

`client = YouTubeIt::Client.new(:dev_key => "my developer key here")`

This worked for me:

```
require 'youtube_it'
client = YouTubeIt::Client.new(:dev_key => "my developer key here")
response = client.videos_by(:query => "penguin")
response.videos.first.title
```

Try something from there:

```
response.videos.each do |video|
  puts video.title
end
```

Result:

```
Pablo Penguin
Emperor penguins - The Greatest Wildlife Show on Earth - BBC
Penguin Fail - Best Bloopers from Penguins Spy in the Huddle
PoM - The Penguin Who Loved Me part 1
Scamper the Penguin (1988) - English Dubbed
Pet Penguin in Japan
Avicii - Penguin (Original mix)
CLUB PENGUIN....
penguin
Penguins very funny
Emperor Penguins in Antarctica
Christina Perri - Penguin (Official Lyric Video)
Club Penguin Unlock Item Codes (NEW) March 2013 Must Watch !!!! (HD)
Emperor Penguins Speed Launch Out of the Water
Avicii - 'Penguin' (Club Mix)
Cookie the Little Penguin at the Cincinnati Zoo
Penguin.avi
DONALD´S PENGUIN  1939
Penguins - BBC
Penguin Dilemma
Very happy Gentoo penguin
Zombie in a Penguin Suit
Penguin One
What should we expect in the next few months in terms of SEO for Google?
槇原敬之 - PENGUIN (2004年 日本武道館)
```

Comment: Just figured this out as well. Thanks, though.